# Slim getBody() function

Tags: php, json, http, post, slim

I have a problem when I try to get some informations about HTTP request from my web application ! I have a REST SLIM API

On the one hand I have :

```
$url = 'http://emannonces.ovh/emannoncesAPI/index.php/api/login';
    $data = array("login" => $_POST["login"], "password" => $_POST["password"]);
    $json_data = json_encode($data);

    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                    'method'  => 'POST',
                    'data' => 'coucou'
            )
    );
```

On the other hand I have the REST API method
But the method at the URL http://emannonces.ovh/emannoncesAPI/index.php/api/login don't get the $login and the $password from the HTTP request and write bool(false) when I do the "echo $parsedBody" :

```
// Connnexion � l'appli
$app->post ( '/api/login', function (Request $request, Response $response) use ($conn) {
    $parsedBody = $request->getBody ();
    echo $parsedBody;
    $login = $parsedBody ["login"];
    $password = $parsedBody ["password"];

} );
?>
```

`getContent(), getParsedBody()` didn't work too...
Help me please aaah

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to print the `post` data in `Slim 3`->

```
$app->post ( '/api/login/', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
 $parsedBody = $request->getParsedBody();
 $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($parsedBody));
}
);
return $response;
```